# Complex integral is zero

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing some complex analysis and I am working on a question, it seems blantanly easy for the answer which is what makes me sceptical. So I would like a second input

Let $C$ be the rectangle with verticies at $\pm b$ and $\pm b+ai$ with $a,b>0$.
I am to explain why this  holds true
$$\int_C e^{-z^2}dz=0$$

In the papers they use a simplified version of Cauchy's integral theorem but to me that would be the reason.

Is that really it or am I missing something? If I am missing something please do enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a direct application of the integral theorem. $e^{-z^2}$ is analytic everywhere.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is analytic everywhere (am I the only one who want's to say "analytical" instead?). Is it really nothing else to it? It just seem so obvious from what they presented I felt it had to be more.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Cauchy's integral theorem says that if $f(z)$ is analytic on an open region $D$, bounded by a closed curve, $c$, then $\int_c f(z) dz=0$. Nothing else to it.

Comment: I knew that but it was just the feeling it had to be more, thank you for confirming what I felt

Comment: @ZelosMalum Complex analysis has the feeling of being too nice. Things somehow fit together *too well* and once you've studied enough badly behaved math, it's somewhat a surprise to get something that behaves nicely. :)